# textarea.val() sends original value not edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have this **textarea** in my **MVC** project

```
<textarea id="edit-content" name="content" placeholder="Text content goes here">@Model.content</textarea>
```

but when I try to send this to a **Json** call like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save() {
        var $title = $('#edit-title'),
            $content = $('#edit-content'),
            $messageLoading = $('#message-edit-loading'),
            $messageError = $('#message-edit-error'),
            $id = $('#edit-id');

        updateComment($id.val(), $title.val(), $content.val())
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data.IsValid()) {
                    $messageError.html('');
                    $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageLoading.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageLoading.html('The text is saved');
                } else {
                    $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageError.html(data.Message);
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, message) {
                $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                $messageError.html('Registration failed: ' + message);
            })
    };
</script>
```

I get the original value of **@Model.content** instead of the new value.

**Edit**

my script.js code

```
function updateComment(id, title, content) {
    return $.get("/Chapter/GetJSON_Update",
        {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            content: content
        },
        'json');
};
```

the entire code from my Edit.cshtml

```
@model Academia_Unitate.Models.Chapter
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit " + Model.title;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_TinyMCE.cshtml")

<div id="edit">
    <h1>
        Edit @Model.type.name
    </h1>

    <div class="" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-title" placeholder="Enter a title" value="@Model.title" required="required" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea id="edit-content" name="content" placeholder="Text content goes here">@Model.content</textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save-btn" onclick="save()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save</button>

        <span id="message-edit-loading" class="alert hidden"></span>
        <span id="message-edit-error" class="alert alert-danger hidden"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="@Model.id" id="edit-id"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function save() {
        var $title = $('#edit-title'),
            $content = $('#edit-content'),
            $messageLoading = $('#message-edit-loading'),
            $messageError = $('#message-edit-error'),
            $id = $('#edit-id');

        updateComment($id.val(), $title.val(), $content.val())
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data.IsValid()) {
                    $messageError.html('');
                    $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageLoading.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageLoading.html('The text is saved');
                } else {
                    $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                    $messageError.html(data.Message);
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, message) {
                $messageError.removeClass('hidden');
                $messageError.html('Registration failed: ' + message);
            })
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What does `updateComment` do? I assume that you mean that it does an AJAX call, but what does the code look like?

Comment: @Guffa: added the **Json** call code

Comment: I don't see any reason why the old value could be sent to the server, it shouldn't exist at all at that stage. You have to debug the code, write out the value at different stages, and/or look at the network traffic to find out exactly where the original value comes into the flow.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have more than one on your page, either make their `id` attributes unique or target the index in your jQuery.

Comment: I've checked the code, and there is no duplicate id called **edit-content**

Comment: Post more code then, what you've given isn't enough. In other words, there's nothing that seems to be wrong with it.

Comment: That's the part that's bugling me as well :-D Everything seems to be right, but the value is still wrong

Comment: Try either `$("textarea[name=content]").val()` or `$("textarea[name=content]").text()` and see what you get.

Comment: hmm tried that just now. Same result. I've checked the console in chrome. and it seems like the data comes directly from the **textarea**, and yet it doesn't change. Even checked the code one more time for duplicates and none is found

Comment: Yea, I'd need to see this actual behavior first hand to inspect it. You may want to setup a jsfiddle for this and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: NOTE: Your issue is client side, not server side